# Is celebrations of Eid-E-Miladun-Nabi Allowed in Islam?

Tags: bidah, islamic-events

Many people of different countries celebrate Eid-e-Miladun-Nabi in remembrance of our prophet Muhammad (SW.). They maintain some traditions like, distributing sweets to the neighbor; pray to Allah for our prophet (SW.); cry for Allah's mercy.

All those are good deeds for sure. But I heard doing something by thinking of it as an islamic-tradition which is not part of Islam is Bidah/Bid'at?

**So, could Eid-E-Miladun-Nabi could turn to Bid'at?**

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq).  Here, we provide a search feature which enables one to search through the questions and answers of this site, before asking something, one should try to search this site to see if the Question was asked.

Comment: I've read the FAQ the moment I've created my account. I searched through before asking. I didn't know it had synonyms (Mawlid Day). Thanks.